# How to add coreplot-cocoaTouch.xcodeproj to my project?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-plot

I am trying to use CorPlot to draw pie charts to display the data but while setting up the project when i am trying to include

```
#import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"
```

it's giving errors saying "No such file or directory". Although i am doing all the necessary steps.

Please let me know if there is something else i need to do except below steps.
1) Download mercurial and get the code through terminal command and save it in a folder.
2) drag n drop the coreplot-cocoaTouch.xcodeproj to my project.
3) Add direct dependency and set the header search path and other linker flag.
4) drag the libCoreplot-CocoaTouch.a to the linker under targets.

Please help!!!

Comment: have u gone through this link : http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the recursive flag in header search path.