# how to remove old points from a graph when new point come ios (by using core plot lib)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I created a graph in my application by using core plot library .the graph shows realtime representation of data when my application added new point into a graph, the graph shrink .
so i want to remove old point from my graph but i don't want to reload my graph . give some alternate way to solve this .

```
  -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self initPlot];
}

#pragma mark - Chart behavior
-(void)initPlot {
    count = 0;
    limit =0;
     currentCountPoint = 1;
    [self configureHost];
    [self configureGraph];
    [self configurePlots];
   // [self configureAxes];
}

-(void)configureHost {
  CGRect  viewRect = CGRectMake(0, 155, 482 ,210);
    //self.hostView = [(CPTGraphHostingView *) [CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
self.hostView = [(CPTGraphHostingView *) [CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];

 UIView *firstGraphView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:viewRect];

    CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( 1.0 / 180.0 * 282.90 );
   [firstGraphView setTransform:rotate];
    self.hostView.allowPinchScaling = YES;


  [firstGraphView addSubview:self.hostView];
     //[self.scrollView2 addSubview:secondGraphView];
     [self.scrollview addSubview:firstGraphView];

//  [self.view addSubview:self.hostView];

}

-(void)configureGraph {
    // 1 - Create the graph
    CPTGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.hostView.bounds];

    [graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTPlainBlackTheme]];

    self.hostView.hostedGraph = graph;
    // 2 - Set graph title
    NSDate *date =[NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [format setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
    NSString *title = [format stringFromDate:date];

    graph.title = title;  
    // 3 - Create and set text style
    CPTMutableTextStyle *titleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    titleStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    titleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    titleStyle.fontSize = 12.0f;
    graph.titleTextStyle = titleStyle;
    graph.titlePlotAreaFrameAnchor = CPTRectAnchorTop;
    graph.titleDisplacement = CGPointMake(0.0f, 10.0f);
    graph.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle = nil;
    [graph.defaultPlotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[graph allPlots]];

    // 4 - Set padding for plot area
    [graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingLeft:02.0f];
    [graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingBottom:02.0f];
    // 5 - Enable user interactions for plot space
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;

    }

-(void)configurePlots {
    // 1 - Get graph and plot space
    CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;

    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    // 2 - Create the three plots
    CPTScatterPlot *aaplPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    aaplPlot.dataSource = self;
    aaplPlot.identifier = CPDTickerSymbolAAPL;
    CPTColor *aaplColor = [CPTColor blueColor];
    [graph addPlot:aaplPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];


    CPTScatterPlot *googPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    googPlot.dataSource = self;
    googPlot.identifier = CPDTickerSymbolGOOG;
    CPTColor *googColor = [CPTColor greenColor];
    [graph addPlot:googPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
     NSLog(@"%d",currentCountPoint);
    CPTScatterPlot *msftPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    msftPlot.dataSource = self;
    msftPlot.identifier = CPDTickerSymbolMSFT;
    CPTColor *msftColor = [CPTColor clearColor];
    [graph addPlot:msftPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
  [self configureAxes];

//  // 3 - Set up plot space

    [plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:aaplPlot, googPlot, nil]];
    //[plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:aaplPlot, nil]];
    //this line calling data source method
    CPTMutablePlotRange *xRange = [plotSpace.xRange mutableCopy];
    [xRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(0.55f)];
    plotSpace.xRange = xRange;
    CPTMutablePlotRange *yRange = [plotSpace.yRange mutableCopy];
    [yRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1.50f)];
    plotSpace.yRange = yRange;

    // 4 - Create styles and symbols
    CPTMutableLineStyle *aaplLineStyle = [aaplPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
    aaplLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.7;
    aaplLineStyle.lineColor = aaplColor;
    aaplPlot.dataLineStyle = aaplLineStyle;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *aaplSymbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    aaplSymbolLineStyle.lineColor = aaplColor;
    CPTPlotSymbol *aaplSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
    aaplSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:aaplColor];
    aaplSymbol.lineStyle = aaplSymbolLineStyle;
    aaplSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(2.5f, 2.5f);
    aaplPlot.plotSymbol = aaplSymbol;


    CPTMutableLineStyle *googLineStyle = [googPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
    googLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0;
    googLineStyle.lineColor = googColor;
    googPlot.dataLineStyle = googLineStyle;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *googSymbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    googSymbolLineStyle.lineColor = googColor;
    CPTPlotSymbol *googSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol starPlotSymbol];
    googSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:googColor];
    googSymbol.lineStyle = googSymbolLineStyle;
    googSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(2.5f, 2.5f);
    googPlot.plotSymbol = googSymbol;


    CPTMutableLineStyle *msftLineStyle = [msftPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
    msftLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0;
    msftLineStyle.lineColor = msftColor;
    msftPlot.dataLineStyle = msftLineStyle;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *msftSymbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    msftSymbolLineStyle.lineColor = msftColor;
    CPTPlotSymbol *msftSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol diamondPlotSymbol];
    msftSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:msftColor];
    msftSymbol.lineStyle = msftSymbolLineStyle;
    msftSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(6.0f, 6.0f);
    msftPlot.plotSymbol = msftSymbol;

//    NSLog(@"%d",currentCountPoint);
 //   int value =20;
   currentCountPoint = currentCountPoint + 1 ;
    if (currentCountPoint < count)
    {
        if(currentCountPoint>10)
        {
            limit =limit +1;

//        NSLog(@"%d",currentCountPoint);
//        NSLog(@"%d",count);
        [self performSelector:@selector(configurePlots) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0];
    }else
    {
        [self configurePlots];
    }
    }

}

-(void)configureAxes {
    // 1 - Create styles
    CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTitleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    axisTitleStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    axisTitleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    axisTitleStyle.fontSize = 12.0f;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *axisLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    axisLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;
    axisLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTextStyle = [[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init];
    axisTextStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    axisTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";    
    axisTextStyle.fontSize = 11.0f;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *tickLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *gridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.50f;
    // 2 - Get axis set
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) self.hostView.hostedGraph.axisSet;
   // CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
//    axisSet.xAxis.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];

    // 3 - Configure x-axis
    CPTAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.title = @"Day of Month"; 
    x.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;    
    x.titleOffset = 50.0f;
    x.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    x.labelingPolicy =  CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    x.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
    x.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    x.majorTickLength = 4.0f;
    x.majorGridLineStyle = gridLineStyle;
    x.tickDirection = CPTSignNegative;

    CGFloat dateCount = [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] datesInMonth] count];

    NSMutableSet *xLabels = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:dateCount];

    NSMutableSet *xLocations = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:dateCount];
    NSInteger i = 0;
    for (NSString *date in [[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] datesInMonth]) {
        CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:date  textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
        CGFloat location = i++;
        //label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(5);
        label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(location);
      //  label.tickLocation = 1.5f;
        label.offset = x.majorTickLength;
        if (label) {
            [xLabels addObject:label];
            [xLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:location]];                        
        }
    }
    x.axisLabels = xLabels;    
    x.majorTickLocations = xLocations;
    // 4 - Configure y-axis
    CPTAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;    
    y.title = @"Price";
    y.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
    y.titleOffset = -40.0f;       
    y.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    y.majorGridLineStyle = gridLineStyle;
    y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    y.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;    
    y.labelOffset = 16.0f;
    y.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    y.majorTickLength = 4.0f;
    y.minorTickLength = 2.0f;    
    y.tickDirection = CPTSignPositive;
    NSInteger majorIncrement = 50;
    NSInteger minorIncrement = 10;
    CGFloat yMax = 300.0f;  // should determine dynamically based on max price
    NSMutableSet *yLabels = [NSMutableSet set];
    NSMutableSet *yMajorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];
    NSMutableSet *yMinorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];
    for (NSInteger j = minorIncrement; j <= yMax; j += minorIncrement) {
        NSUInteger mod = j % majorIncrement;
        if (mod == 0) {
            CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", j] textStyle:y.labelTextStyle];
            NSDecimal location = CPTDecimalFromInteger(j); 
            label.tickLocation = location;
            label.offset = -y.majorTickLength - y.labelOffset;
            if (label) {
                [yLabels addObject:label];
            }
            [yMajorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:location]];
        } else {
            [yMinorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:CPTDecimalFromInteger(j)]];
        }
    }
    y.axisLabels = yLabels;    
    y.majorTickLocations = yMajorLocations;
    y.minorTickLocations = yMinorLocations;
    }

#pragma mark - Rotation
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}

#pragma mark - CPTPlotDataSource methods
-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot {

    count =[[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] datesInMonth] count];
    NSLog(@"%d",currentCountPoint);
    NSLog(@"%d",count);
    return  currentCountPoint;
}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    NSUInteger valueCount =  count;
    switch (fieldEnum) {
        case CPTScatterPlotFieldX:
            if (index < valueCount) {

                return [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:index];
            }
            break;
                    case CPTScatterPlotFieldY:
            if ([plot.identifier isEqual:CPDTickerSymbolAAPL] == YES) {
                return [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] monthlyPrices:CPDTickerSymbolAAPL] objectAtIndex:index];
            } else
                if ([plot.identifier isEqual:CPDTickerSymbolGOOG] == YES) {
                return [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] monthlyPrices:CPDTickerSymbolGOOG] objectAtIndex:index];
                }  else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:CPDTickerSymbolMSFT] == YES) {
                    return [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] monthlyPrices:CPDTickerSymbolMSFT] objectAtIndex:index];
                }       break;
    }
    return [NSDecimalNumber zero];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-deleteDataInIndexRange:` method on the plot to remove data points without hitting the datasource for new data. See the "Real Time Plot" demo in the *Plot Gallery* example app for sample code.

Comment: from where i get a sample code of this kind of work .

Comment: i am Download the sample code from coreplot gallery but the code having error coreplot lib missing when  iam adding that library into the sample code the no of error increase .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918244/how-to-add-coreplot-cocoatouch-xcodeproj-to-my-project this type of issue

Comment: there is a -(void)updateGraph  method to update the graph and remove the old point from the graph . i got that method in some code put it hard to understand can you please help me in this

Comment: Post the code from your `-updateGraph` method so we can see what it does.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207454/real-time-line-graph-with-core-plot-not-updating-plot-range  go to that link in ques you find the update method .

Comment: You should ask a new question if you're having trouble understanding parts of the `-updateGraph` method. The comments in the code describe the basic steps—ask for clarification on the parts that are confusing.